# How do I exit() the python script within terminal when I press the 'Escape' key?

Tags: python, terminal, keyboard

The objective here is to exit the script once the escape key is pressed, without having to make a guess for a letter first. I think is problem is that the input() isn't detecting 'esc' as a keypress. So at the moment I have to guess a letter, press 'enter', then press the 'esc' kay to exit the script.

```
def main():  
      import random
      import keyboard
      import sys
       
      # Main program code....
    
      # Keep asking the player until all letters are guessed
      while display != wordChosen:
        guess = input(str("Please enter a guess for the {} ".format(len(display)) + "letter word: "))[0]
        guess = guess.lower()
        #Add the players guess to the list of used letters
        used.extend(guess)
        print ("Attempts: ")
        print (attempts)
        
        while True:
         if keyboard.read_key() == 'esc':
          print("Exiting...")
          sys.exit(0) # this exits your program with exit code 0
        
        # Search through the letters in answer
        for i in range(len(wordChosen)):
          if wordChosen[i] == guess:
            display = display[0:i] + guess + display[i+1:]
    
        print("Used letters: ")
        print(used)
      
        # Search through the letters in answer
    for i in range(len(wordChosen)):
      if wordChosen[i] == guess:
        display = display[0:i] + guess + display[i+1:]
    
    print("Used letters: ")
    print(used)
        
    # Print the string with guessed letters (with spaces in between))
    print(" ".join(display))
        
        # more code....
```

This is the terminal output below, I believe the issue is getting the input() for '.guess' to acknowledge the keyboard press of 'esc', but I'm not sure how to do this? As you can see the '^[' is picked up but doesn't instantly exit the script unless I press 'enter'. Apologies, wasn't sure how to properly paste in text from terminal.

```
Please enter a guess for the 5 letter word: ^[
Attempts: 
0
Exiting...
^[%
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "continue" OR "exit" the program by pressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733662/how-to-continue-or-exit-the-program-by-pressing-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have try this kind of example in documentation:

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', lambda: exit(0))
```

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks for your help, however I have added in the `else: break` as the while True loop keeps going resulting in the input() function not registering the letter key press. But by adding the `else: break` the 'Esc' no longer works. is there a syntax issue here or something else going on which I am missing?
`while True:
     if keyboard.read_key() == 'esc':
      print("Exiting...")
      sys.exit(0) # this exits your program with exit code 0
     else:
        break`